# Simple select from a source and nHibernate can't take it

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Why is it that nHibernate is designed to not permit building a simple class on, as example "select [column list] from someview/table/sproc" where there isn't any key?

Especially where I'm NOT going to persist any of the recordset back to the database?

This is a very basic function of any application, simply present some data to the user.

What do you do to workaround this?
Why approaches:
1) build a row id column in the view

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(... as 'recid' -- calculate a row number for each record set.
```

nHibernate:

```
{"Could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]"}
InnerException : {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
InnerException : null
```

**AFTER** it has already received the recordset form the database.
This issue is because nHibernate is not built to understand how it will not be the code that writes to a database and it assumes absolutely all intentions is that any entity will be written to by nHibernate.

This is my map of the 'recid':

```
<id name="recid" column="recid" type="int">
    <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

2) remove the ROW_NUMBER() 'recid' column from the view & change the mapping from an `<id>` node and change that to `<composite-id>` ~ after all I do have a natural key in the data so I'll just have nHibernate create it's own even though nothing will ever need it.

This is my map of the composite:

```
<composite-id name ="recid" type="int">
    <key-property name="s_recid" column="s_recid" type="int" ></key-property>
    <key-property name="c_recid" column="c_recid" type="int"></key-property>
</composite-id>
```

nHibernate:
Which just can't be done because no matter what I can nolonger get nHibernate to compile my mapping file.  It states:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: Sets.hbm.xml ---> 
NHibernate.MappingException: Problem trying to set property type by reflection ---> 
NHibernate.MappingException: class System.Int32 not found while looking for property: s_secid ---> 
NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for property 's_recid' in class 'System.Int32'
```

No matter what I do or how arrange things this is always the response.
If I swap lines 9 & 10 (swap the key-properties s_recid & c_recid then the problem becomes c_recid doesn't have a getter.

No matter what the first element in the composite-id doesn't have a getter.

But back to my original question.
Why is it that nHibernate is designed to not permit building a simple class on a select from a table where there isn't any key when I never going to persist any of the recordset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a mapping file in case you are looking for a projected class. You need to make your query with any querying method and then use `Select` to describe your projection.

Tailing to the select, you can describe your transformation and the easiest would be if your DTO properties match with the select column, so you can use `AliasToBean`

```
var query = session.Query<MyDataClass>().Where(x => x.Name == "Axel");
var projection = query.Select(d => 
    new MyDto { field1 = d.Name, field2 = d.SomethingElse })
    .ToList();
```

If you use results coming from SQL queries or stored procedures, you can use result transformer:

```
var results = query
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(MyDto)))
    .List<MyDto>();
```

Comment: You know you are right.  I forget I can query just about anything like this.  But I do like a mapping->My classes attributes.  Straight forward, clean, simply done.  Through on some LINQ and that's a nice small manageable code.  But I'll see what I can do with this construction which I'd forgotten.

Comment: I went with hbm.Session.CreateQuery() instead.  I just didn't want to also have the overhead of maintaining a DTO class. Do you know why using CreateQuery() still requires a mapping?  Seems unnecessary.